# I cant read data from array despite that am storing before reading. I need help. C

Tags: arrays, c, string

Am working on a project where i have a communication between two apps. The main up reads data from a file where the other up writing into it. The code is working fine but the error is when server reads "import.string" i want to split this message and store the string into a public char array in order to use this string after for other operations. Despite that am storing the string **first**and the current function where the store is it prints the string , when am trying to read the new index where the new string is, in another function  it returns null and i dont know why. I will post this two function where the operations are.The other code is working the main problem is there that IsValid() function  cant read the data where Initialize() function stores to public char arra informations.

```
char *informations[REGS_NUM][SIZE]; /*Informations about registers*/


void Initialize(char *receive_message,Request *request){

    char *token=NULL,*useful_info=NULL;
    char *store_tokens[5];
    int stable=0;
    
    useful_info=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

    token=strtok(receive_message,".");
    int i=0;
    while(token!=NULL){
        i++;
        store_tokens[i]=token;
        token=strtok(NULL,".");
    }
    useful_info=store_tokens[i];
    
    count_registers++;
    
    informations[count_registers][stable]=useful_info;
    printf("informations[%d][0]=%s\n",count_registers, informations[count_registers][stable]);
    
}
int IsValid(char *value, Request /*rep*/ *request)
{
    
    char  *first_num=NULL,*last_num=NULL,*token,*useful_info;
    char info_cpy[12]; 
    char *store_tokens[5];
    int stable = 0,num;

    useful_info=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
 
    sprintf(useful_info,"%s",informations[request->ID][stable]);
    printf("informations[%d][0] : %s\n",request->ID,useful_info);
    //first_num = strtok(useful_info,"|-"); /*Store first value */
    token=strtok(informations[request->ID][stable],"|-");
    int i=0;
    while(token != NULL){ /*Run and store the other values into store_tokens array*/
        i++;
        store_tokens[i] = token;
        token  = strtok(NULL,"|-");
    }
    last_num = store_tokens[i]; /* Give the i-st which is the last index of store_tokens array*/ 
    num = atoi(value);
    if ( num < atoi(first_num) || num > atoi(last_num)){  
        return 0;
    }else {
        return 1;
    }   
   

}
```

An example is here :
server reads an import string "0-100" , he stores the string into the public char array informations and prints it from the function Initialize() but after when the IsValid function

```
needs to read it returns null
informations[3][0]=0-100 // from Initialize()
message received : AT+REG3=10
ID : 3
informations[3][0] : //from IsValis()
[1]    3301 segmentation fault  sudo ./server /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: *"i want to split this message and store the string into a public char array in order to use this string after for other operations."* - this has the distinct aroma of misunderstanding that `strtok` (a) modifies the input buffer to establish the tokens, and (b) returns pointers within said-same buffer, which you're storing directly. Therefore, the lifetime of all of those pointers is hitched *directly* to the lifetime of the original `receive_message` address and whatever buffer is backing that. If that expires, so do all those pointers. Going with that sans a proper [mcve].

Comment: In addition your code contains a bunch of *magic* constants for sizes (`char info_cpy[12];` or `char *store_tokens[5];`), but you never control out of bound accesses. Unsure whether it is a problem here, but if some input causes an access past end of array, Undefined Behaviour is there.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you help  me how to avoid this problem ?